# st_within for entire table

Tags: sql, coordinates, gis, postgis

Most st_within methods I see are comparing one point

I want to be able to tell if my coordinates are within many points, an entire table's worth, because I

basically like

select attributeA, attributeB from regions where lat, lon st_within = true

this is a psuedoquery as this isn't the syntax for the st_within method, but how would I go about doing this with st_within which appears to only take one geometry at a time, and I'm not sure how to dynamically set up multiple st_within methods for an entire table

Comment: Could you rewrite your question? Maybe show what you have and what you want? Do you want to check if st_within is true for ALL rows in the table or do you want to select the rows for which it is true?

Comment: @JakubKania I would like to select the rows for which it is true

Comment: So how is that diffrent from all the other examples?

Comment: @JakubKania link? I did end up having trouble converting my lat, lon to the proper SRID for the geoms

Comment: So I'm guessing you have multiple points you want to query against the table at the same time?

Comment: @JakubKania just one point, its probably not a complicated question actually so you dont have to overthink it

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE ST_WITHIN(ST_SETSRID(ST_MAKEPOINT(<lat>, <lon>)<srid>),geom);` has to work then.